# Improve condition check

Tags: java, java-8

Need best  approach in the following scenario,

I've list of  attributes like source , destination, Yes/No as below:

```
Example: 
source ,  destination , Yes/No
abc, bcd, Yes
abd, gdc, Yes
```

In java  i can go with  condition like

```
if(Obj.getSource().equals("abc")) {
   if(Obj.getDest().equals("bcd")) { 
      return true;
   }
}

if(Obj.getSource().equals("abd")) {
   if(Obj.getDest().equals("gdc")) { 
      return true;
   }
}
```

In this way i can handle the above case , based on the resultant Yes , i can handle my business logic.

But my approach was two many check  and , lines of codes to lengthy, 
Please suggest me  good approach in java7 or java8.

Comment: Can you use logical operators like **logical and** `&&` or **logical or** `||`? In that case you could simply write `if ((first && second) || (third && fourth)) { return true; }` with the respective conditions.

Comment: Note that you should stick to **naming conventions**. Variable names start with a lower-case character (assuming `Obj` is a variable though). In that case `obj` would be a more appropriate name.

Comment: Just i mentioned the pseudo code ,  so I used Obj,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just combine all four conditions into one using **logical operators**. For example by using **logical and** `&&` and **logical or** `||`. It could then look like:

```
if ((first && second) || (third && fourth)) {
    return true;
}
```

Or with all conditions substituted:

```
if ((Obj.getSource().equals("abc") && Obj.getDest().equals("bcd"))
        || (Obj.getSource().equals("abd") && Obj.getDest().equals("gdc"))) {
    return true;
}
```

Note that you may memorize the result of `Obj.getSource()` and `Obj.getDest()` in a variable in order to save some performance and make the condition more readable by using that variable instead.

And if you would `return false;` in the other cases you could even completely leave out the whole `if` as you could directly return the `boolean` resulting after evaluating the condition (it evaluates to either `true` or `false`, no need to return `true` and `false` hardcoded then):

```
return (first && second) || (third && fourth);
```

Comment: Its good approach ,  but   if no  of condition more than 5 ,  sonar link  simply ,  not good practice ,                                                                             
 if ((Obj.getSource().equals("abc") && Obj.getDest().equals("bcd"))
        || (Obj.getSource().equals("abd") && Obj.getDest().equals("gdc"))) {
    return true;
}      ,Is there any approach using java8 parallel  streams

Comment: I don't see how that stream should look like. I mean the structure of the condition is always the same, it is two **and** and then both together with **or**. This really is the simplest it can get. As said if your goal is to get rid of a long condition inside if, you may do `boolean result = (first && second) || third && fourth);` and then `if (result)` or directly `return result;`

Comment: Even i tried ,  there is no stream matching to this problem statement , I'm Iterating the over the for loop and and maintaining array of each column attributes  and  compare each index  , based on the matching ,  return true

Comment: Well, if you are iterating something you always convert this to a `Stream`. However in this case we would need the whole code, especially the part including the iteration. The condition-part which you showed will however probably stay the same, even if using streams.